# redux check state at componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

in my react component, I have two attributes in the state, one in local react state and the other in Redux store.

```
    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchExercise(this.props.params.id);
    }    
     constructor(props) {
       super(props); 
       this.state = {editeMode: false}
   }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return {currentExercise: state.currentExercise}
   }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchExercise})(createNewExercisePage);
```

so according to the path; `/new-exe/:id` currentExercise in Redux is either empty or something is fetched. editeMode is in React. now I want to check if I have something in `currentExercise` `editemode:true` else it should be false (according to false and true I am showing different buttons).
I tried it (with lodash) in `componentWillMount(){... this.setState({editeMode:_.isNull(this.props.currentExercise)})}`
but it does not work, it reamins false.
generaly in these cases that first should fetch something then check it, what should be the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in componentWillMount ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)). The documentation also says that "setting state in this method will not trigger a re-rendering", so I guess that means that the setted value will be ignored.

You are not going to change the value of the `editeMode` entry in the store unless the value of `this.props.currentExercise` changes, and so it does not serve much purpose to keep track of the changes in order to update the store. Just use the value directly. In your particular case, I would do the following:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchExercise(this.props.params.id);
}    
constructor(props) {
   super(props); 
   this.state = {}
}

render(){
    const editeMode = _.isNull(this.props.currentExercise);
    // The rest of your render logic, using editeMode instead of this.state.editeMode
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {currentExercise: state.currentExercise}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchExercise})(createNewExercisePage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in 
`componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ editeMode: !nextProps.currentExercise) });
}
```

Redux will make sure the props get updated.

You should also consider putting the `editMode` state in Redux instead.